# how to reset a part of the form

Tags: jquery

I have a markup like this

```
<form>
    <div class="pane1">
        <input type="text" class="form element1">
        <input type="text" class="form element1">
    </div>
    <div class="pane2">
        <input type="text" class="form element2">
        <input type="text" class="form element2">
    </div>
    <div class="pane3">
        <input type="text" class="form element3">
        <input type="text" class="form element3">
        <input type="text" class="form element3">
    </div>
</form>
```

now I need to clear the all text boxes box inside pane3 using jquery
is that possible.

thanks

Comment: maybe `$('.pane3 > input').val('');`

Comment: @sujith you have to check out jquery selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove or hide all input text boxes under pane3 div then please use under css style sheet --

.pane3 input[type='text']{display:none;}

or

if remove value of input boxes then use this --

$('.pane3 input').val(' ');

Answer (score 1):

instead of selecting each `input` you can select all inputs inside pane3 div

try this

```
$('.pane3 input').val('');
```

Comment: this is not happening for radio group

Comment: this will work for radio....but select box and textarear you need to add corresponding selector

Answer (score 0):

```
var username=$("#spTxtUsername").val();
var password=$("#spTxtPassword").val();
```

// Do Some Operation

```
$("#spTxtUsername").val("");
$("#spTxtPassword").val("");
```

if you are using Class

$(".form-element-3").val("");

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.pane3 input').val('');
```

select input elements by pane3 class and setting their values to empty..

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```
$('.pane3 input').val('');
```

or even more specific

```
$('.pane3 input.element3').val('');
```